# overload assignment operator, rhs is a function call

Tags: c++, class, oop, operators, overloading

I overload the assignment operator for some class c1, and I also overload the addition operator, for addition of class c1 and c2. When I use them as follows:

```
// signatures of the overloaded operators:
c2 c1::operator+(c2 & obj_c2);
c1& c1::operator=(c2& obj_c2);


// use them like this:
c1 obj1;
c2 ojb2;
obj1=obj1+ojb2;
```

This compiles to failure. But if I use a temporary object, it works:

```
c1 obj1;
c2 ojb2, temp;
temp=obj1+ojb2;
obj1=temp;
```

The compiler I used is g++, how can that be a problem without a temporary object?

Comment: Either make the addition operator return a reference, or add another assignment operator that takes a value.

Comment: I recommend you check [the canonical operator overload implementations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations). Notice how the argument to the assignment operator is a reference to a *`const`*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look carefully at your implementation of *operator=*:

```
c1& c1::operator=(c2& obj_c2);
```

Here *operator=* accepts its argument by *reference*. But references cannot bind to temporary objects. In the second example reference binds to *temp*, which is not a temporary, so it works.

To solve the problem change your *operator=* to:

```
c1& c1::operator=(const c2& obj_c2);
```

which should work.

Comment: Thanks, it works! That means temporary object can be const referenced, although it cannot be referenced.